# does string contain only underscores

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex solution that either checks whether a string *only* consists of underscores `___`.

`/[a-z]/` doesn't work, neither does `[^_]`

Comment: Only the *specs*?  No evidence of what you tried.

Comment: Your question and examples contradict one another.

Comment: Did you try a regular expression that didn’t work, or get anywhere with one? Debugging is always helpful in answering a question. (For example, `[a-Z]` is wrong. It would usually be written `[A-z]`, but that’s still wrong.)

Comment: Are any other characters allowed? Like dashes, slahses, etc? Otherwise `^_*$` should match a string containing only zero or more underscores.

Comment: @joe776 And for that you don't even need regular expressions :)

Comment: if you want to test for not only _ then you can do `trim($string, "_") == "")`;

Comment: @Jack Yes, I've seen your answer :) I didn't know that function, but haven't used PHP in the last years.

Answer (score 2):

To check if string has underscores you can simply use  - `_+`

To check if string has letters or numbers use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

You've semi answered yourself in question. Anway it was easy to find and you should do some research before posting question here.

Everything is about putting the characters in regex class with is defined by [] and giving '+' to this class which means one or more.

You can also use or operator which is `|`

`/^(_+|[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)$/`

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mVlLDr)

Comment: This will also match AAA###, because the A is in your regex. The solution to this would be to check if there are any different chars

Comment: To *check* either of those, why use `+`?

Comment: @Martijn this won't match string that contains `#`.

Comment: @minitech because + means one or more, what's the better option? `*` will allow string that may not contain these characters.

Comment: Note:  [\w]+ is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9]+

Comment: @PeteBelford: Note: `\w+` is the same as `[\w]+`

Comment: @PeteBelford Nay, `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`; you missed the underscore.

Comment: @minitech I've changed good point.

Comment: @PeteBelford it's not the same it has also `_` :)

Answer (score 2):

Only underscores? Try this:

```
/^_+$/
```

This will match a string consisting of one or more underscores. It will not match an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string only consists of underscores:

```
if (strspn($str, '_') == strlen($str)) {
    // only underscores
}
```

See also: [`strspn()`](http://php.net/strspn)

Theoretically, an empty string also only consists of underscores; if that's undesirable you would need to also check whether `strlen($str)` is non-zero.

Comment: Oh, that’s an interesting way to do that.

Comment: Performancewise this _might_ be a bad way. You are calling two functions, each with overhead and executiontime. But be interesting to benchmark the different methods

Comment: @Martijn Benchmarks or it didn't happen ;-)

Comment: @Jack, thats exactly what I said :P it _might_ be faster/slower and benchmarking this could be fun

Comment: @Martijn Well, my answer is 20% faster =P

Comment: Compared to which function?

Comment: @Martijn Compared to a `preg_match('/^_*$/', $str)`

Comment: Ahh, that explains the huge difference, regex isn't fast ^^ how about `trim($string, "_")===""` (edit: and maybe try `rtrim()` and `ltrim()`? )

Comment: My answer is 9% slower than a `trim()` operation; of course, at the scale we're talking this is quite insignificant unless you perform this 100k+ times :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it. The regex check if you have any other chars, and the trim does the check for underscores only

```
if( !preg_match("/[^0-9a-z\_]/si", $string) && trim($string,"_")!=""){
    // Code here
}
```

You have changed your post. You can do either of these

```
if( trim($string,"_")=="") ){ /* _ only */ }
if( str_replace("_", "", $string)=="") ){/* _ only */}
if( !preg_match("/^_/si", $string) ){/* _ only */}
```